# Python use of class to create and manipulate a grid

Tags: class, python-3.x

Still trying to understand how to use class. I have now written the following:

```
`import random
class Grid():
    def __init__(self, grid_row, grid_column):
        self.__row = grid_row
        self.__col = grid_column
        self.__board=[]

    def make_board(self):
        for row in range(self.__row):
            self.__board.append([])
            for col in range(self.__col):
                self.__board[row].append('0')
        return self.__board

    def change_tile(self):
        choices = (0,1,2)
        x = random.choice(choices)
        y= random.choice(choices)
        self.__board[x][y] = str(2)

    def __repr__(self):
        for row in self.__board:
            print( " ".join(row))


g = Grid(3,3)
g.make_board()
g.change_tile()
print(g)
```

Firstly when I run this I get a grid printed followed by:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

I don't understand why this happens. Second question. If I want to return the self.**board, __str** only returns the last row (0,0,0).With 'print' all three rows and columns are printed. Is there a way around the issue with 'return'?Is it an issue ( apart from the fact that I want to 'see' what I am doing)?
How would one call Grid(3,3) and get a grid with a randomly placed 2 without having to call each function separately as I have done in my example? Lastly why can I not use the integers 0 or 2, but have to convert everything to a string?. I hope that I have not exceeded the goodwill that exists on this forum by asking so many dumb questions!

Answer (score 1):

The special methods `__repr__` and `__str__` are *required* to return a string. If there is no `__str__` implementation given, the `__repr__` will be used for the string conversion too.

Now in your case, `__repr__` *prints* something instead of returning a string. It actually returns nothing, so `None` is implicitely returned. You have to change it to return a string. For example like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in self.__board])
```

Comment: I now get nothing at all or if I call the change_tile method, the whole thing bombs as  "File "/Users/admin/Desktop/coursera_computing_course/grid_board.py", line 19, in change_tile
    self.__board[1][2] = str(2)
IndexError: list index out of range